# How to add images to website dynamically from a folder in the hosting server

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I made a website for somebody, and for the first time I had to host it online. I bought a domain and hosting service, and added my website.

Immediately I discovered that all my photos in the gallery page, which were added dynamically to the website via the code down below, doesn't work anymore. So, the code selected all the images from the folder and added them to html. Now, from what I read, I need to set the src of the images to the web server address(for example, the folder with the images'https://example.ro/imgsite/imgsite-galerie/Cabana/').

How can I do it so it will select all the photos automatically as it was when I run the page locally on my computer?

This is the code, so sectionSelector select the section where the images will be posted, imageSrc is the address of the photo, and dataLightBox is for the gallery.

```
function getImages(sectionSelector, imageSrc, dataLightbox) {

    // get a reference to the container element where the images will be added
    let container = document.querySelector(`#${sectionSelector}`);
    // define the URL of the image folder on your server
    let imageUrl = imageSrc;
    let lightbox = dataLightbox;
    // make a request to the server to get a list of all the image files in the folder
    fetch(imageUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            // create a temporary div element to hold the HTML returned by the server
            let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.innerHTML = html;

            // select all the <a> elements in the temporary div that link to image files
            let imageLinks = tempDiv.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".gif"]');

            // loop through the <a> elements and dynamically generate HTML code for each image
            for (let i = 0; i < imageLinks.length; i++) {
                let imageSrc = imageLinks[i].getAttribute('href');
                let imageHtml = '<a href="' + imageSrc + '" data-lightbox= "'+ lightbox +'" ><img src="' + imageSrc + '"></a>';
                container.innerHTML += imageHtml;
                console.log(imageSrc);
                console.log(imageHtml);
            };
        });
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
getImages('g-sct-HanulAncutei','imgsite/imgsite-galerie/Hanul\ Ancutei/', 'HanulAncutei');
getImages('g-sct-cabana','imgsite/imgsite-galerie/Cabana', 'cabana');
getImages('g-sct-others','imgsite/imgsite-galerie/OthersImg', 'others');
});
```

For example, when I call function getImages(), to auto select all the photos in the web hosting server folder I choose

Comment: Does replacing  `let imageUrl = imageSrc;` with  `let imageUrl = 'https://example.ro/imgsite/imgsite-galerie/Cabana/';` works?

Comment: no, the same problem :(